# Activate different workbook to run macro

Tags: excel

I created a macro in my workbook using an active worksheet from another workbook. I would now like to run my macro, but use yet another different active workbook to get my data.

I have this line 20 times in my macro...

Windows("IFS_round_1").Activate

...so I do not want to change it (ex. IFS_round_2) each time I open a new workbook to run the macro. Is there something I can add so the macro just uses whichever active workbook I have open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to refer to the workbook. For example:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    wb.Activate

    'DO CODE HERE
End Sub
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are opening the other workbook programatically,  but this solution works. basically you just save the handle to the other workbook as soon as you open it.

```
sother_filename = "IFS_round_1"
'saves the name of the current workbook
curr_workbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'opens the new workbook, this automatically returns the handle to the other
'workbook (if it opened it successfully)
other_workbook = OpenWorkbook(sother_filename)
```

But what fun is that? one more solution to automatically get the workbook name when **there are only two workbooks open** and then simply use that to call the other workbook

```
Function GetOtherWBName()
    GetOtherWBName = ""

    'if we dont have exactly two books open
    'we don't know what to do, so just quit
    If (Workbooks.Count) <> 2 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    curr_wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'if the active workbook has the same name as workbook 1
    If (StrComp(curr_wb, Workbooks(1).Name) = 0) Then
        'then the other workbook is workbook 2
        GetOtherWBName = Workbooks(2).Name
    Else
        'then this is the other workbook
        GetOtherWBName = Workbooks(1).Name
    End If

End Function
```

So now in the workbook that  has the macro make a button and assign a macro to it similar to this

```
Sub ButtonClick()
    'first we save the current book, so we can call it easily later
    curr_wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    other_wb = GetOtherWBName()

    If Len(other_wb) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("unable to get other wb")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'now to call the other workbook just use
    Workbooks(other_wb).Activate

    'all the rest of your code
End Sub
```